# Automatic notification system about changes to court cases

Tags: performance, php, api, curl

I have written an application for lawyers' offices. There is an API to fetch info about court cases. I have implemented API calls for front end when user enters particular case; one tab is filled with info from this API about this case's state in court.

This code is run from a daily cron job; for all the cases in my application, it checks the `last updated filed` and matches it with last saved `last updated filed` in my DB. If they don't match, then the notification system in my app informs assigned people of the changes on that case.

So in short: automatic notification system about changes on all court cases in my app and email.

I'm a bit new to curl and PHP API calls, usually using JS, so bear with me.

I have some performance issues with this script. The DB call and loop is only around 70 times. And it's a bit slow. I'm afraid whether it will even work at all with bigger numbers.

Side note: API does not have option to fetch all data at once. I have to loop it so:

1. First API call is made in `function eSudovi()` and data is saved `$eSudovi`.
2. There is a function `function findSudCode($val, $eSudovi)` to filter that data and get some info from it in loops.
3. DB get data is made and for each row one new API Call is made `with function ePredmeti($sud, $pred)` with `$epredmet = ePredmeti($sudCode, $sudBroj);` inside loop.
4. I stopped here because it is pretty slow. And I will need additional logic inside loop.

As I'm new to curl in PHP I am looking for suggestions on improving this. I have been told something can be maybe done with opening and closing connections every time?

I have implemented checking of times, as recommended in [Trying to access array offset on value of type null & isset problem in API call loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68181117/4850040). It looks like the times are all over the place, not connected to type of response.

I'm using PHP version 7.4.

```
// ONE API CURL CALL AT START
function eSudovi()
{
    $endpoint = "xxx";
    $qry = '{"query":"query{sudovi {id, sudNaziv}}"}';

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $qry);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($result, true);
}

// SAVE DATA FOR LATER USE
$eSudovi = eSudovi()["data"]["sudovi"];

//FILTER THAT DATA FROM LATER LOOP
function findSudCode($val, $eSudovi)
{
    foreach ($eSudovi  as $key => $value) {
        if ($value["sudNaziv"] == $val) {
            return $value["id"];
        }
    }
}


// 2nd API CURL CALL THAT IS USED IN LATER LOOP
function ePredmeti($sud, $pred)
{
    $endpoint = "xxx";
    $qry = '{"query":"query{ prvi:predmet(sud: ' . $sud . ', oznakaBroj: \"' . $pred . '\") {lastUpdateTime}}"}';

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $qry);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($result, true);
}




// DB GET DATA

$results = mysqli_query($con, "
                SELECT DISTINCT predf_nas_br, predf_odv,  predf_SUD, predf_SUDBROJ
                FROM PREDMETIFView 
                WHERE predf_SUD <> '' AND predf_SUDBROJ <> '' AND predf_SUDBROJ NOT LIKE '% %'
                UNION ALL   
                SELECT DISTINCT predp_nas_br, predp_odv,  predp_SUD, predp_SUDBROJ 
                FROM PREDMETIPView 
                WHERE predp_SUD <> '' AND predp_SUDBROJ <> '' AND predp_SUDBROJ NOT LIKE '% %'
                ;");
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {

// LOOP THAT BD DATA
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == "predf_nas_br") {
            $nas = $value;
        }

        if ($key == "predf_SUD") {
            $sud = trim($value);
            if (!empty($sud) && isset($sud)) {
                $sudCode = findSudCode($sud, $eSudovi);
            }
        };

        if ($key == "predf_SUDBROJ") {
            $sudBroj = trim($value);
        };
       


        if (!empty($sudCode) && !empty($sudBroj) && isset($sudCode) && isset($sudBroj)) {
            // echo $sudCode . "<br>";
            // echo $sudBroj . "<br>";
            $epredmet = ePredmeti($sudCode, $sudBroj);

            print_r($epredmet);
            echo "<br>";

            if (isset($epredmet["data"]["prvi"]["lastUpdateTime"])) {
                $lastUpdateTime = $epredmet["data"]["prvi"]["lastUpdateTime"];
                $dateTime  = str_replace("T", " ", $lastUpdateTime);
                echo $nas . " - " . $dateTime . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**EDIT:**

To address anwser ive got:

Mysql Query took 0.0002 seconds for 52 results, and I don't see how would that be problem, it is done once and I said there is only around 70 results per testing DB. Anyway everything is properly indexed etc...

I have added user agent to curl and have implemented [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68178645/trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-null-isset-problem-in-api-call/68181117#68181117) solution with class that should address reusing of curl connection.

I have also created code so you can all test it out with sample data and endpoints:

```
$arr = [
    ["Županijski sud u Zagrebu", "13-Kir-t-us-330/20"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu", "P-2315/96"],
    ["Upravni sud u Splitu", "Uslgr-66/2020"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu", "P-2282/2018"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu", "P-785/2020"],
    ["Općinski kazneni sud u Zagrebu", "K-1899/2019"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu", "P-12107/2019"],
    ["Županijski sud u Osijeku", "K-Us-9/2019"],
    ["Županijski sud u Zagrebu", "K-Us-11/2018"],
    ["Općinski sud u Splitu", "Z-27820/20"],
    ["Općinski prekršajni sud u Zagrebu", "Pp-226/2020"],
    ["Općinski prekršajni sud u Zagrebu", "Pp-5211/2021"],
    ["Općinski prekršajni sud u Zagrebu", "Pp-5142/2021"],
    ["Upravni sud u Zagrebu", "Usl-348/20"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu", "P-2931/2021"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu", "Z-36742/2010"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu", "Z-20259/2020"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu, ZK odjel", "Z-29964/2020"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu", "Pn-3651/2017"],
    ["Općinski radni sud u Zagrebu", "Pr-1676/2015"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu", "P-1037/2008"],
    ["Općinski sud u Kutini", "Pn-160/2019"],
    ["Trgovački sud u Zagrebu", "Povrv-912/2018"],
    ["Trgovački sud u Zagrebu", "P-1637/2019"],
    ["Trgovački sud u Zagrebu", "P-1560/19"],
    ["Trgovački sud u Zagrebu", "P-1318/2018"],
    ["Trgovački sud u Zagrebu", "P-1477/2018"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu, ZK odjel", "Z-58743/19"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu, ZK odjel", "Z-49863/2019"],
    ["Općinski sud u Sesvetama, ZK odjel", "Z-440/2014"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu", "Pn-2545/2018"],
    ["Općinski sud u Splitu, ZK odjel Supetar", "Z-20786/2019"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu, ZK odjel", "Z-34316/2020"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu, ZK odjel", "Z-34825/12"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu, ZK odjel", "Z-55780/2013"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu, ZK odjel", "Z-36302/2016"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu", "Ovr-1465/2019"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu", "P-766/2019"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu", "Ovr-375/2020"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu", "R1-555/2020"],
    ["Trgovački sud u Zagrebu", "R1-4/2021"],
    ["Općinski sud u Splitu", "P-4300/2020"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu", "Z-52429/2019"],
    ["Općinski sud u Novom Zagrebu", "Z-22493/2019"],
    ["Općinski sud u Sesvetama", "Z-10836/2019"],
    ["Općinski sud u Sesvetama", "Z-10833/2019"],
    ["Općinski radni sud u Zagrebu", "Pr-3823/2021"],
    ["Općinski radni sud u Zagrebu", "Pr-3326/2021"],
    ["Općinski građanski sud u Zagrebu", "Z-5768/21"],
    ["Općinski radni sud u Zagrebu", "Pr-13210/2020"],
    ["Općinski radni sud u Zagrebu", "Pr-3936/2021-2"],
    ["Upravni sud u Zagrebu", "Usl-49/18"]
];



function eSudovi()
{
    $endpoint = "https://e-predmet.pravosudje.hr/api/";
    $qry = '{"query":"query{sudovi {id, sudNaziv}}"}';

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

    $ch = curl_init();
    $agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $qry);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($result, true);
}


$eSudovi = eSudovi()["data"]["sudovi"];

function findSudCode($val, $eSudovi)
{
    foreach ($eSudovi  as $key => $value) {
        if ($value["sudNaziv"] == $val) {
            return $value["id"];
        }
    }
}



class ePredmeti
{
    public $epredmet;
    private $curl, $ini_opt;

    function __construct()
    {
        $endpoint   = 'https://e-predmet.pravosudje.hr/api/';
        $headers    = ['Content-Type: application/json'];
        $timeout = 30;

        $agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)';

        $this->curl = curl_init();
        $this->ini_opt = [
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $agent,
            CURLOPT_URL => $endpoint,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => $timeout,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => $timeout
        ];
    }

    public function _exec($sud, $pred)
    {
        $start = microtime(true);

        $query_opt = [
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>
            '{"query":"query{ prvi:predmet(sud: ' . $sud . ', oznakaBroj: \"' . $pred . '\") {lastUpdateTime}}"}'
        ];
        curl_reset($this->curl);
        curl_setopt_array($this->curl, $this->ini_opt);
        curl_setopt_array($this->curl, $query_opt);
        $ret = curl_exec($this->curl);

        if (!curl_errno($this->curl)) {
            if (curl_getinfo($this->curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) !== 200) {
                echo 'HTTP error: ' . $http_code . '<br>';
                $this->epredmet = null;
            } else {
                $this->epredmet = json_decode($ret, true);
            }
        } else {
            echo curl_error($this->curl) . '<br>';
            $this->epredmet = null;
        }

        echo 'Took: ' . (microtime(true) - $start) . '<br>';
    }
}



$mycurl = new ePredmeti();

foreach ($arr as $value) {

    $sudCode = findSudCode(trim($value[0]), $eSudovi);
    $sudBroj = trim($value[1]);

    if (!empty($sudCode) && !empty($sudBroj) && isset($sudCode) && isset($sudBroj)) {
        // echo $sudCode . "<br>";
        // echo $sudBroj . "<br>";
        $mycurl->_exec($sudCode, $sudBroj);

        // var_dump($mycurl->epredmet);
        // echo "<br>";

        if (isset($mycurl->epredmet["data"]["prvi"]) && !empty($mycurl->epredmet["data"]["prvi"])) {

            if (isset($mycurl->epredmet["data"]["prvi"]["lastUpdateTime"]) && !empty($mycurl->epredmet["data"]["prvi"]["lastUpdateTime"])) {
                $lastUpdateTime = $mycurl->epredmet["data"]["prvi"]["lastUpdateTime"];
                $dateTime  = str_replace("T", " ", $lastUpdateTime);
                echo $dateTime . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This testing script is a bit faster for some reason but still times varies from 0.01 to 5, 6 sometimes 7 sec. And in production I still get 504 Gateway Time-out on one DB.

Im afraid to do this on large number of records...

Any other suggestions welcomed.

**EDIT:**

It just got to my attention that this GraphQL APi does support multiple cases in one request, it just needs alias in front. So my problems are solved...

Answer (score 2):

Tip: reusing the curl handle keeps the connection to the server open. Since you are marking repeated request against the same host, this should speed up things. Use `$ch = curl_init();` at the start of your code, out of the `ePredmeti` function in order to reuse your curl instance.

But you are not saying what part of the code is slow. We cannot test it, or you should provide a public URL. I suggest that you add a few prints in your code and inside the functions, to spit out a timestamp and you will see where the bottlenecks are.

Could be as simple as:

```
echo(date('d/m/Y H:i:s', time()));
```

Then you can figure out which part needs optimizations.

The database query itself also could be taking a long time, because it is not optimized, and very likely does not take advantage of table **indexes** (if they even exist). You should measure the average time of that query separately, and use the query plan (use the `explain` command in Mysql) to try to make this query perform better, if you find that is indeed taking a long time to run. It mainly depends if you have lots of records in your table or a moderate number.

It is also possible that the website applies some form of rate limiting and slowing you down. You should spoof the **user agent** to a mainstream browser (use `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`), because it is obvious to the website that your script is a bot. They can decide to penalize you and throttle traffic.

Comment: Please include that `!empty() && isset()` is an antipattern that shouldn't exist in anyone's application for any reason.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4559976/2943403

Comment: I have edited my question with test code and did address some points come up in this post. Thanks for answering.

Comment: It just got to my attention that this GraphQL APi does support multiple cases in one request, it just needs alias in front. So my problems are solved...